# AND logical operator on 3 columns with OR in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I am trying to make a boolean search program where the user inputs a keyword and it gets searched in my dataframe. I managed to do a 1-word search but I am having trouble with 2 words search input. I am taking 2 words from the user and trying to search and print them out but it doesn't seem to work. I have 4 columns - One_key, Two_key, Three_key, link.

I am trying to search word_y in (one or two or three key) AND word_z in (one or two or three_key)

```
,One_key,Two_key,Third_key,link
0,parliament,laws,agricultural,www.xyz.com
1,population,supreme court,ampc,www.zyx.com
2,protest,road,blockades,www.fdw.com
3,violence,tweeted,batons,www.jsa.com
4,Rihanna,tweet,government, www.xyz.com
5,barbadian,Chris Brown,together, www.ici.com
```

the code:

```
if x == '2':
print("enter the 2 words to search:")
y = input()
z = input()
logic = input("Enter number for logic: 1. AND 2. OR \n")
if logic == '1':
    and_logic = keyword[(keyword["One_key"]==y) | (keyword["Two_key"]== y) 
                                        | (keyword["Third_key"]==y)] &
        keyword[(keyword["One_key"]==z) | (keyword["Two_key"]== z) 
                                        | (keyword["Third_key"]==z)]
    print((and_logic)
```

how to write and operation between y and z inputs?

Answer (score 0):

You already have everything you need, just chaining up `&` and `|`.
It could be something like this,

```
found_y = (keyword["One_key"]==y) | (keyword["Two_key"]== y) | (keyword["Third_key"]==y)
found_z = (keyword["One_key"]==z) | (keyword["Two_key"]== z) | (keyword["Third_key"]==z)
and_logic = keyword[found_y & found_z]
or_logic = keyword[found_y & found_z]
```

To make it cleaner,

```
cols = ["One_key", "Two_key", "Third_key"]
found_y =(keyword[cols]==y).any(axis="columns")
found_z =(keyword[cols]==z).any(axis="columns")
and_logic = keyword[found_y & found_z]
or_logic = keyword[found_y & found_z]
```

Comment: so I tried this but it doesn't return anything. Both of the entered values are in the dataframe but it still it returns an empty dataframe with AND logic operator. I mean shouldn't it print both the rows containing the entered value?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#Printing dataframe:
    One_key     Two_key         Third_key           link
0   parliament  laws            agricultural       www.xyz.com
1   population  supreme court   ampc               www.zyx.com
2   protest     road            blockades          www.fdw.com
3   violence    tweeted         batons             www.jsa.com
4   Rihanna     tweet           government         www.xyz.com
5   barbadian   Chris Brown     together           www.ici.com
```

Now based on the Input variables, we try to create `bool` column:

```
#As an example
y = 'laws'
z = 'www.jsa.com'
logic = 2

df['result'] = (df.applymap(lambda x: x==y).sum(axis=1) + df.applymap(lambda x: x==z).sum(axis=1))
df['bool'] = df['result'].apply(lambda x: x==2 if logic == 1 else x==1)
```

Output:

```
    One_key Two_key     Third_key              link           result          bool
0   parliament  laws           agricultural     www.xyz.com      1            True
1   population  supreme court  ampc             www.zyx.com      0            False
2   protest     road           blockades        www.fdw.com      0            False
3   violence    tweeted        batons           www.jsa.com      1            True
4   Rihanna     tweet          government       www.xyz.com      0            False
5   barbadian   Chris Brown    together         www.ici.com      0            False
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I want to print the row with the values that match the user's keyword. So like if y = barbadian and z = protest so row 2 and 5 prints out. Sorry if my question wasn't clear.

Comment: For getting those rows just add this to the end of my code:
`df.loc[df['bool']]`
and you get those rows.